# How To Implement ReverseAJAX (Comet) in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ajax, comet, reverse-ajax

How could I implement a Comet architecture in a ASP.Net MVC?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The paid alternative

There are great comments about the question in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65673/comet-implementation-for-asp-net).

And based in the fact you can use handlers in a MVC app:

**[WebSync](http://www.frozenmountain.com/websync)**

will do the work : )

Answer (score 4):

I doubt you will find something out of the box for MVC but you can always implement the client side code that handles timeouts and reconnects to an AJAX-enabled WCF service that polls for whatever event you want to be notified for. Be sure to set the timeout of the service to a higher value.

Edit 24.11.2013
Since the original question was posted SignalR was released which is a library to do just that.

Answer (score 4):

As long as you need to implement server push support onto your ASP.NET MVC application you will need some extra functionalities like detection of client status etc. I suggest you to try [PokeIn](http://pokein.com) comet ajax library which you can find sample project [here](http://pokein.codeplex.com)