# How to send data many times to web browser in response to one request?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, long-polling

I have a form on my web page, it allows to submit many queries to my website,
every query is on a separate line in TextArea. Because waiting for all queries to complete is 
too long I would like to update the web page after every query completes - send result of one query to a web browser, new result should be appended to old results that are already on the web page.

How to do this in ASP.NET MVC 2?

I will be grateful for helpful responses.

**Update**

Thank you for all your answers but I decided to use JavaScript in web browser to poll server for data, here is my question about it
[Can't disable jQuery cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908936/cant-disable-jquery-cache)

Answer (score 2):

Read about [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29)

Some projects from **codeplex**:

- [ncomet](http://ncomet.codeplex.com/)
- [pokein](http://pokein.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I've read it, it is too general. I was hoping for some code examples in ASP.Net MVC.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259633/how-to-implement-reverseajax-comet-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: there are samples on PokeIn side

Answer (score 0):

I would just flush using `Response.Flush()` each time when you complete part of the request.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [HTTP Server Push](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_streaming) or *Long Polling*.

or this SO question on HTTP Streaming...

[Cross-browser implementation of "HTTP Streaming" (push) AJAX pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112413/cross-browser-implementation-of-http-streaming-push-ajax-pattern)

Examples of *Long Polling* with generic code.

[How do I implement basic "Long Polling"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333664/simple-long-polling-example-code)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/long-polling