# Very long running XmlHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-ajax

I am writing an application which needs "near real-time" updates from a browser app.  The other requirement is that it use as little as possible bandwidth (so polling is not an attractive option).  My idea is to use an `XmlHttpRequest` and just let the server wait to respond to that request until there is something to send back.  This could be anywhere from seconds to 8-12 hours.

Questions:

1. Is an XmlHttpRequest going to wait that long for a response?
2. Is my ASP.NET MVC service (hosted under IIS7) going to allow a request to sit that long?
3. What would be the maximum number of users a server could support under this configuration?  Are we going to run out of threads in the thread pool before we get a reasonable number of people with open requests?
4. Is there a better way to fill these requirements?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) instead of Ajax.  Unfortunately I don't have any personal experience with Comet, and basically know nothing other than the fact that it exists, so this isn't going to be an answer.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Comet implementation for ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65673/comet-implementation-for-asp-net) and see if that will help you.  A common example for using comet is web based chat applications, which has a similar requirement to your "seconds to 8-12 hours" statement.