# How do I implement a Push-Pull web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, architecture

The data is either in files or databases.

I want to implement data grids which will pull data from files (either .h5, csv or xml) and sql server database and show them being updated in real time.

I don't want to implement a timer which has few seconds interval.  I want to implement a pull push technology in asp.net/c#/silverlight which I could use?

Please guide how best to implement it and if there are any libraries available that I can use?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Having any problems? Any code to show? These 3 questions should set the bar as to whether you should post a question or use google for research..

Comment: nope, haven't tried anything. i dont want to code anything that i might have to delete later so wanted to get some feedback from experts like yourself to ensure i follow the right path in developing this app

Comment: If I didn't code things that might get thrown away later, I'd never have learned or developed anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the [PokeIn ASP.NET Comet Library](http://pokein.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 3):

Look into [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29). Also check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65673/273200) (and answers).

Answer (score 2):

You could look into [Websockets](http://www.undisciplinedbytes.com/2010/06/html-5-c-web-sockets-server-and-asp-net-client-implementation/), be aware the end users will need to have a websocket [enabled browser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSockets) and also note the following from wiki

> For the client side, WebSocket was to
>   be implemented in Firefox 4, Google
>   Chrome 4, Opera 11, and Safari 5, as
>   well as the mobile version of Safari
>   in iOS 4.2.[1](http://www.undisciplinedbytes.com/2010/06/html-5-c-web-sockets-server-and-asp-net-client-implementation/) However, although
>   present, support is now disabled by
>   default in Firefox and Opera because
>   of concerns over security
>   vulnerabilities

Comment: There's a websocket implementation for SilverLight. Which makes writing the backend easier because SilverLight is microsofty.

Answer (score 0):

WCF tech in a publisher-subscriber or observer pattern. Or SQL Server Service Broker notifications with a SqlDependency object. Or CLR stored procs that notify clients from within the DB.