# Communication between a Client -> WCF Service -> ASP.NET Webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web-services, visual-studio-2008

i try to build a Client which sends data to a WCF Service. There is an ASP.NET Webpage which should recieve those information and put them in textfields etc.

Here is the method in my client:

```
 OutlookPluginService.BookingRequest breq = new OutlookClient.OutlookPluginService.BookingRequest();
            breq.subject = "This is my subject";
            breq.numParticipants = 6;

            client.getBookingURL("1234", breq);
```

This method sends the data to the WCF Webservice and recieves the ASP.NET URL.

This is my WCF Method:

```
 public string getBookingURL(string guid, BookingRequest request,string token,string exitURL)
{
    BookingRequest breq = new BookingRequest();

    HttpContext current = HttpContext.Current;
    string baseUrl = current.Request.Url.Scheme + "://"
        + current.Request.Url.Authority
        + current.Request.ApplicationPath.TrimEnd('/') + '/'
        + "WebPage/Booking/BBooking.aspx";
    return baseUrl;
}
```

i can access to the data from here but i dont know how to transfer the data to the asp.net Webpage.

is it possible to solve this problem with sessions?

thanks in advance for your help/ideas

Comment: WPF? You mean WCF, right?

Answer (score 0):

you have two options;

1) you may use pooling, which makes calls to the related service in predetermined time intervals to fetch the newly added data.

or

2) you may use a pull - push structure which enables you to push data from your WCF service to your ASP.NET application. Refer to [How do I implement a Push-Pull web application in C# asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060791/how-do-i-implement-a-push-pull-web-application-in-c-sharp-asp-net)