# How to Auto Update post without any page load in ASP.NET(Like Google+)?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, telerik, google-plus

I am developing a web application like facebook News feed or Google + Stream page. I am using ASP.NET  , Telerik Rad Ajax control and Azure Cloud service.
For Example:  I have 2 User:  User1 and User2.
User1 and User2 both are online and the same page is open in different PC. 
When User 1 Share (Post) a Messages then how to update the page of User2 without any page reload(Like Google+)?

Thanks 
Nahid

Comment: Check out http://www.lightstreamer.com/ and [comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want to do some long-polling. BAsically you fire off a request through ajax, that request is handed off to a seperate thread, which waits for an answer, before returning the request.

There's an example of a chat using long-polling here:

http://blogs.claritycon.com/blog/2011/04/12/roll-your-own-mvc-3-long-polling-chat-site/

Comment: Thanks Atheist, for you reply. I am using ASP.NET 3.5 not MVC. Can you give me a example for ASP.NET...

Comment: I haven't looked through all the answers here, but it seems like there's something here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65673/comet-implementation-for-asp-net