# DevExpress - Show Alert Window for all users in app

Tags: winforms, devexpress

We've got a program that runs on our network (it's published to our app-server and run from there as well) and I'd like to show an Alert window (by DevExpress) to all users who are running the app, whenever a new item is entered.  Obviously the code would go in the Save event but when I put it in there, it only works for me, meaning I'm the only user who sees the alert, no one else.  The same can be said for other users...they only see the alert when they enter it, not when someone else enters it.

Any ideas as to how this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use straight MSMQ to put on a message and have clients listen on that queue.  You can also use NServiceBus (which does use MSMQ) that has a publish subscribe framework built in.  This way your clients can subscribe to all clients or certain clients.

Since WinXP, Vista and Win7 have MSMQ it just maybe a matter of installation and configuration (which NServiceBus will do 'automatically' for you)

Answer (score 0):

You could try with [Comet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65673/comet-implementation-for-asp-net) if you want true push mechanism. Otherwise you could use periodical pull using setInterval and ajax calls. However, both techniques have some performance repercussions.

Comment: I believe Comet is for web apps, correct?  This is a windows app...thanks for the comment though.