# asp.net mvc3 razor, javascript, server to client communication

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I had created a webpage using asp.net mvc3 razor. I have two master pages one for dealer and one for admin.
 For dealer, i displayed the data from the 'claims' table in webgrid. It shows fine.

For admin, i provided the facility that he can add the claims for the dealer...

My question is, I want the dealer to get the updated information without any page refresh.
i.e when the server got the new data in the claims table i want to get the data to the dealer without any page refresh.

Is it possible. How to get it.Can any one provide me the solution..

Comment: This is pretty vague. So the vauge answer is: yes it's possible, you use Ajax, you start writing it. Are you having a specific problem?

Comment: Thank you for Your answer. I had mentioned that i am using asp.net mvc3 and used webgrid. I need some thing more not just an ajax call or settimeinterval all that. I am searching some thing like comet implementation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disagree with all implementations here - its all old info (sorry guys!) Theres a great MODERN solution available in signalR, dont even consider anything else : )

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR

Comment: HTML is getting quite old too... :o)

Answer (score 0):

Agree with 32bitkid, it's a fairly vague question. You might want to have a look at [Period Refresh with Ajax](http://ajaxpatterns.org/Periodic_Refresh) as a strarting point to understand the principles involved.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with a pub/sub solution, or a so called Comet solution

[Comet implementation for ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65673/comet-implementation-for-asp-net)

This way the client does not poll a service it gets the new data pushed from the server