# ASP.NET how to push notification to client (same as Gmail)

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can i push notification to client same as Gmail do?
which technology should i use?

Answer (score 5):

For an ASP.NET implementation, have a look at [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR).

Comment: SignalR will use web sockets and if web sockets are not supported by browser then it will use polling.

Comment: @Sam Yep, but anyway you will use either web sockets or polling, than it's better to use library like SignalR than do it yourself

Answer (score 0):

You need to create or reuse a Comet implementation. 
This has already been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65673/comet-implementation-for-asp-net).

More details about this design approach can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29).