# How can I "push" notifications to webapp using ExtJS / JS / Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I wish to create a shared calendar web app where all users can see the same calendar.
Each time one user creates and event , I want all other users to see that events without the need to refresh the web app.
Is there a way to "push" notification or I must use a timer to update the site every second?

Answer (score 0):

I only can recommend websockets.

If you use Apache with PHP at the backend, the bad news is that Apache does not support websockets. The good new is that there exist great solutions which allow you to write such a service in plain PHP in a few lines. I use [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/) with success and a minimal effort.

For asp.net, I don't know what solutions exist, but I think you will find what you need by googling. There is also a related [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65673/comet-implementation-for-asp-net).