# How to implement comet or reverse ajax on MVC application Razor view

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

i'm currently looking for an sample code regarding the comet implementation or Reverse Ajax of sending data from server to client im currently using MVC application back-end code is c# and java script as my script / Jquery Can you provide a simple sample regarding this matter? i just need to send a data on the server which will receive in client side.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr) to achieve this functionality and it's doing an even better job that what you are trying to do, because it attempts to use Websockets first.

### SignalR

> HTML 5 transports
>
> These transports depend on support for HTML 5. If the client browser
>   does not support the HTML 5 standard, older transports will be used.
>
> WebSocket (if the both the server and browser indicate they can
>   support Websocket). WebSocket is the only transport that establishes a
>   true persistent, two-way connection between client and server.
>   However, WebSocket also has the most stringent requirements; it is
>   fully supported only in the latest versions of Microsoft Internet
>   Explorer, Google Chrome, and Mozilla Firefox, and only has a partial
>   implementation in other browsers such as Opera and Safari. Server Sent
>   Events, also known as EventSource (if the browser supports Server Sent
>   Events, which is basically all browsers except Internet Explorer.)
>   Comet transports
>
> The following transports are based on the Comet web application model,
>   in which a browser or other client maintains a long-held HTTP request,
>   which the server can use to push data to the client without the client
>   specifically requesting it.
>
> Forever Frame (for Internet Explorer only). Forever Frame creates a
>   hidden IFrame which makes a request to an endpoint on the server that
>   does not complete. The server then continually sends script to the
>   client which is immediately executed, providing a one-way realtime
>   connection from server to client. The connection from client to server
>   uses a separate connection from the server to client connection, and
>   like a standard HTML request, a new connection is created for each
>   piece of data that needs to be sent. Ajax long polling. Long polling
>   does not create a persistent connection, but instead polls the server
>   with a request that stays open until the server responds, at which
>   point the connection closes, and a new connection is requested
>   immediately. This may introduce some latency while the connection
>   resets.

Answer (score 1):

You can check these:
Top 20 NuGet packages for Comet http://nugetmusthaves.com/Tag/Comet
[Comet implementation for ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65673/comet-implementation-for-asp-net)
https://pokein.codeplex.com/
Creating Comet applications with ASP.NET http://www.aaronlerch.com/blog/2007/07/08/creating-comet-applications-with-aspnet/
and a lot more by googling.

Comment: Hi i have tried the last link that you gave me is it possible to return a json data in that approach i tried but its now working?